# Pandas: Inventory recalculation given a final value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm coding a Pyhton script to make an inventory recalculation of a specific SKU from today over the past 365 days, given the actual stock. For that I'm using a Python Pandas Dataframe, as it is shown below:

```
Index   DATE    SUM_IN  SUM_OUT
0      5/12/18   500        0
1      5/13/18    0      -403
2      5/14/18    0       -58
3      5/15/18    0       -39
4      5/16/18   100        0
5      5/17/18    0       -98
6      5/18/18   276        0
7      5/19/18    0      -139
8      5/20/18    0       -59
9      5/21/18    0       -70
```

The dataframe presents the sum of quantities IN and OUT of the warehouse, grouped by date. My intention is to add a column named "STOCK" that presents the stock level of the SKU of the represented day. For that, what I have is the actual stock level (index 9). So what I need is to recalculate all the levels day by day through all the dates series (From index 9 until index 0).

In Excel it's easy. I can put the actual level in the last row and just extend a the calculation until I reach the row of index 0. As presented (Column E is the formula, Column G is the desired Output):

[image: Inventory Recalculation on Excel]

Does someone can help me achieve this result?

I already have the stock level of the last day (i. e. 5/21/2018 is equal to 10). What I need is place the number 10 in index 9 and calculate the stock levels of the other past days, from index 8 until 0.

The desired output should be:

```
Index   DATE    TRANSACTION_IN  TRANSACTION_OUT SUM_IN  SUM_OUT STOCK
0      5/12/18         1                 0        500      0     500
1      5/13/18         0                 90        0     -403     97
2      5/14/18         0                 11        0     -58      39
3      5/15/18         0                 11        0     -39      0
4      5/16/18         1                 0        100      0     100
5      5/17/18         0                 17        0     -98      2
6      5/18/18         1                 0        276      0     278
7      5/19/18         0                 12        0    -139     139
8      5/20/18         0                 4         0    -59       80
9      5/21/18         0                 7         0    -70       10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated)

```
last_stock = 10  # You should try another value
a = (df.SUM_IN + df.SUM_OUT).cumsum()
df["STOCK"] = a - (a.iloc[-1] - last_stock)
```

Comment: That's also is not yet what I need

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

By using `cumsum` to create the key for `groupby` , then we using `cumsum` again

```
df['SUM_IN'].replace(0,np.nan).ffill()+df.groupby(df['SUM_IN'].gt(0).cumsum()).SUM_OUT.cumsum()
Out[292]: 
0    500.0
1     97.0
2     39.0
3      0.0
4    100.0
5      2.0
6    276.0
7    137.0
8     78.0
9      8.0
dtype: float64
```

Update

```
s=df['SUM_IN'].replace(0,np.nan).ffill()+df.groupby(df['SUM_IN'].gt(0).cumsum()).SUM_OUT.cumsum()-df.STOCK
df['SUM_IN'].replace(0,np.nan).ffill()+df.groupby(df['SUM_IN'].gt(0).cumsum()).SUM_OUT.cumsum()-s.groupby(df['SUM_IN'].gt(0).cumsum()).bfill().fillna(0)
Out[318]: 
0    500.0
1     97.0
2     39.0
3      0.0
4    100.0
5      2.0
6    278.0
7    139.0
8     80.0
9     10.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but that's not what I desire. 

What I have in hands is the dataframe presented (Index, DATE, SUM_IN, SUM_OUT) and I want to add to it another column named STOCK. 

I already have the stock level of the last day (i. e. 5/21/2018 is equal to 10). What I need is to calculate the stock levels of the other past days, from index 8 until 0. 

The desired output should be:

`Out[1]: 
0    500.0
1     97.0
2     39.0
3      0.0
4    100.0
5      2.0
6    278.0
7    139.0
8     80.0
9      10.0
dtype: float64`

Comment: @ArnoldSouza seems like you need `(df['SUM_IN']+df['SUM_OUT']).cumsum()
`, ummm....

Comment: Nope. If I use cumsum, it will calculate the accumulate sum from 5/12/18 until 5/21/18. What I want is the other way around. I Have the Stock Level of 10 at 5/21/18 and I want to figure out how much was the stock level in the other past days.