# Inventory recalculation given a final value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm coding a SQL Server script to make an inventory recalculation of a specific SKU from today over the past 365 days, given the actual stock. In the scrip I do a lot of data cleaning manipulation. In the end, the output is produced from a temporary table, as presented:

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV='IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_IN, --COUNT TRANSACTIONS IN
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV='OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_OUT, --COUNT TRANSACTIONS OUT
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV ='IN' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_IN, --SUM QUANTITY IN
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV ='OUT' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_OUT --SUM QUANTITY IN
FROM #MOVIMENTS
GROUP BY DT
ORDER BY DT
```

Bellow is possible to see an output example of the SQL shown:

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjXIL.png)

The table presents the sum of transactions as well as quantities IN and OUT of a warehouse, grouped by date. My intention is to add a column named "STOCK" that presents the stock level of the SKU of the represented day. For that, what I have is the actual stock level. So what I need is to recalculate all the stock levels day by day through all the dates series.

In Excel it's easy. I can put the actual level in the last row (for example: 10) and just extend the calculation (formula presented in the image) until I reach the top. As presented (Column E is the formula, Column G is the Output):

[Inventory Recalculation on Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhREV.png)

Does someone can help me achieve this result in SQL Server?

In Python I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458342/pandas-inventory-recalculation-given-a-final-value), using Pandas, but I would prefer to implement this calculation inside the SQL Script.

Comment: Hint: look at SUM() OVER ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d072c/45)

Based on the idea of @EzLo I figure out a solution to this problem.

```
DECLARE @cum_sum float -- scalar cumulated sum
DECLARE @last_stock float = 10 -- current stock level

-- get the last value of the cumulated sum 
SELECT TOP 1 @cum_sum = SUM(SUM_IN + SUM_OUT) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) FROM t ORDER BY DATE DESC

-- final select
SELECT 
  *,
  RunningSum = SUM(SUM_IN + SUM_OUT) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) - (@cum_sum - @last_stock)
FROM t
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a running (or windowed) sum.

```
;WITH PartialResults AS
(
    SELECT
        DATE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MOV='IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_IN, --COUNT TRANSACTIONS IN
        SUM(CASE WHEN MOV='OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_OUT, --COUNT TRANSACTIONS OUT
        SUM(CASE WHEN MOV ='IN' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_IN, --SUM QUANTITY IN
        SUM(CASE WHEN MOV ='OUT' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_OUT --SUM QUANTITY IN
    FROM #MOVIMENTS
    GROUP BY DT
)
SELECT
    P.*,
    RunningSum = SUM(P.SUM_IN + P.SUM_OUT) OVER (ORDER BY P.Date ASC)
FROM
    PartialResults AS P
```

Comment: Hi, I could see that this instruction can give me the cumulative sum as "RunningSum". That's not yet what I'm looking for. I already have the last stock level. Using that, my intention is to calculate the levels of the previous days (considering (P.SUM_IN + P.SUM_OUT)).

Comment: @ArnoldSouza Then use `ORDER BY P.Date DESC` and add your final stock to the SUM(), like 10 + `SUM() OVER ()`

Answer (score 0):

[SQL FIDDLE Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a6c0d/3)

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV='IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_IN, --COUNT TRANSACTIONS IN
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV='OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_OUT, --COUNT TRANSACTIONS OUT
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV ='IN' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_IN, --SUM QUANTITY IN
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOV ='OUT' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_OUT --SUM QUANTITY IN
INTO #newtable
FROM #MOVIMENTS t1
GROUP BY DT
ORDER BY DT

select t1.DATE, t1.TRANSACTION_IN, t1.TRANSACTION_OUT, t1.SUM_IN, t1.SUM_OUT, SUM(t2.SUM_IN + t2.SUM_OUT) as STOCK
from #newtable t1
inner join #newtable t2 on t1.DATE >= t2.DATE
group by t1.DATE, t1.TRANSACTION_IN, t1.TRANSACTION_OUT, t1.SUM_IN, t1.SUM_OUT
order by t1.DATE
```

Comment: That instruction result in the cumulative sum from the older until the newest date. I already have the newest date (i.e. @last_stock int = 10) and I want to run a SQL to get the other previous stock levels considering SUM_IN and SUM_OUT